# how to join various bits of string and data together using python

Tags: python, string

Python newbie here. I've been working my way through this code to basically create a string which includes a date. I have bits of the code working to get the data I want, however I need help formatting to string to tie in the data together.

This is what I have so far:

```
def get_rectype_count(filename, rectype):
    return int(subprocess.check_output('''zcat %s |  '''
                                       '''awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"};{print $6}' | '''
                                       '''grep -i %r | wc -l''' %
                                       (filename, rectype), shell=True))

str = "MY VALUES ("
rectypes = 'click', 'bounce'
for myfilename in glob.iglob('*.gz'):
        #print (rectypes)
        print str.join(rectypes)
        print (timestr)
        print([get_rectype_count(myfilename, rectype)
                               for rectype in rectypes])
```

My output looks like this:

```
clickMY VALUES (bounce
'2015-07-01'
[222, 0]
```

I'm trying to create this output file:

```
MY VALUES ('2015-07-01', click, 222)
MY VALUES ('2015-07-01', bounce, 0)
```

Comment: Why not just tie together the pieces of the string with the string concatination operator? I.e. a+b . Also, if the print statement contains a trailing comma, it will not output a newline character.

Comment: `str` is a built-in type, you shouldn't redefine it. Very confusing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call join on a string it [joins together everything in the sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) passed to it, using itself as the separator.

```
>>> '123'.join(['click', 'bounce'])
click123bounce
```

Python supports formatting strings using [replacement fields](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> values = "MY VALUES ('{date}', {rec}, {rec_count})"
>>> values.format(date='2015-07-01', rec='click', rec_count=222)
"MY VALUES ('2015-07-01', click, 222)"
```

With your code:

```
for myfilename in glob.iglob('*.gz'):
    for rec in rectypes:
        rec_count = get_rectype_count(myfilename, rec)
        print values.format(date=timestr, rec=rec, rec_count=rec_count)
```

edit:

If you want to use `join`, you can join a newline, `\n`:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(['line1', 'line2'])
line1
line2
```

Putting it together:

```
print '\n'.join(values.format(date=timestr,
                              rec=rec,
                              rec_count=get_rectype_count(filename, rec))
                for filename in glob.iglob('*.gz')
                for rec in rectypes)
```

Comment: Thanks for making it look easy.

Comment: I was testing the other solution using `join`. Got the following syntax `error: for filename in glob.iglob('*.gz')
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @noober there was a missing closing parenthesis for `.format(`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
str1 = "MY VALUES ("
rectypes = ['click', 'bounce']
K=[]
for myfilename in glob.iglob('*.gz'):
        #print (rectypes)
        #print str.join(rectypes)

        #print (timestr)
        k=([get_rectype_count(myfilename, rectype)
                               for rectype in rectypes])

 for i in range(0,len(rectypes)):
      print str1+str(timestr)+","+rectypes[i]+","+str(k[i])+")"
```